# Angular.io unit test component with HTTP

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

Background

I have an angular4 component (MemberListComponent), an http GET request will be invoked to fetch the list member from backend through MemberService during ngInit. The returned members will be listed in table. The MemberService is injected into the MemberListComponent and acted as an member variable.

Question

Now, I want to draft an unit test to verify the correctness for displaying the returned members. Shall I create a FakeBackend to mock up the MemberService and the returned members for testing the MemberListComponent.

Or, do we have any patterns or examples for this use case.

To control the unit test execution.

We can use 'BeforeEach' to execute some logics before each test case. 
If I want to execute some logic before particular test case, how can we achieve that?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either create a mock for your service or spy on the actual service. Refer to the official documentation about [testing a component with an async service](https://angular.io/guide/testing#test-a-component-with-an-async-service).

This is how you would spy on the method `getQuote` of the `twainService`
(excerpt from official docs, within `beforeEach` of your test):

```
// get hold of your service instance
twainService = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(TwainService);

// on service call, return your test data
spy = spyOn(twainService, 'getQuote')
      .and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(testQuote));
```

If your service returns an Observable instead, you need to change `Promise.resolve(...)` to `Observable.of(...)`

Comment: Thanks, Kim. Could you share me some codes for a quick reference.

Comment: Just check the code examples in the documentation, e.g. "src/app/shared/twain.component.spec.ts (setup)" for spying on your service

Comment: Kim, your example is useful and helping me to move forward. I have another question - about controlling the execution of unit test. We can use 'BeforeEach'  to execute some logics before each test case. If I want to execute some logic before particular test case, how can we achieve that?

Comment: If it applies only to just one test case, then execute it within that test case. Of course you can put the initialization in its own method and then call that method. The before and beforeeach are only for shared initializations.